# pyqt5 How to recognize which qpush_button activates the function in this function?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

Like in topic. I looking for a way to recognize which qpush_button activates the function in this function.

Comment: for example I have 3 push_buttons: 

push_button_1 
push_button_2 
push_button_3 

whole is connect with one function named "how_active"

If I press push_button_3 -> how_active return ex. push_button name.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this.  One is to include some additional data in the function call via *partial* functions.  The other way is to use the Qt *sender()* method

```
self.button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.button_clicked(self.button1))
self.button2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.button_clicked(self.button2))

def button_clicked(self, button):
    print button
```

The other way is to use the [`sender()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#sender) method

```
self.button1.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
self.button2.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

def button_clicked(self):
    print self.sender()
```

Comment: Thx for help :)